# How to track down reason for slow SQLite query

Tags: python, sqlite

I've got a SQLite DB that's accessed by several processes (a python web service, with a separate process per request, with infrequent writes taking place).

One query often seems to either block or take a very long amount of time (~15-30 seconds in many cases):

```
SELECT x, COUNT(x) FROM table1 GROUP BY x
```

The table has ~40,000 rows, 3 unique values of `x`, and around 10 columns.

If I execute the query either from python (using the `sqlite3` module), or from the command line using the `sqlite3` binary, I often get the same slow behaviour. After running the query once, it's usually very fast afterwards.

How can I best find out what's making this slow? Is there a way to check if it's blocking on anything, or waiting on any write locks/transactions to be released?

Comment: [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) is usually a good starting point for SQL related performance issue debugging, though it'll not help you with any locking issues etc.

Comment: Do you have an [INDEX](https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on `x`?

Comment: If one successful query speeds up new queries over other processes then the latency might originate from slow I/O.

Comment: @amuttsch no INDEX, but I didn't think a full row scan on ~40k values would be a problem.

Comment: Have you tried it with an index? If you don't want to alter the table in production, just copy it elsewhere, do the `create index` and try the query and check if it runs faster. To check time use `.timer on|off          Turn SQL timer on or off`

Comment: @amuttsch just tried it, no change at all with an index. One the steps listed by EXPLAIN is to obtain a table lock though, so I'm guessing that it's possible some other process still has it locked, just not sure how to check that.

Comment: Additionally, if I make a copy of the DB and run the query, it completes almost instantly, which also points to it being blocked on some lock.

Comment: You can check your `insert`, `update` and `delete` statements if one has a slow where clause. You can read more about locks [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)